# Spring Bach transaction roll back

Tags: spring-batch

I'm going to transfer data from csv to mysql database.
I any error occurs during CSV->DB conversion I need to rollback the entire transaction and not only data of current chunk.
in my simple-job.xml is

```
<batch:job id="jobSimple" job-repository="jobRepository" parent="simpleJob">
     <batch:step id="step1">
      <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
       <batch:transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT" propagation="REQUIRED" timeout="30"/>
       <batch:chunk reader="cvsItemReader" processor="Pprocess" writer="databaseItemWriter" commit-interval="100"/>
      </batch:tasklet>
     </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "rollback entire transaction"? because transaction are bounded around chunk. Do you want to delete inserted data from database?

Comment: yes i want rollback entire transaction.

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031186/spring-batch-one-transaction-over-whole-job as starting point

Comment: i need off-line processing