# Transaction Management across multiple steps in Spring Boot Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am using Spring Boot Batch for creating my Batch Processing System.
I have around 10 different steps writing data in Same Database using Spring Boot Data JPA Repositories.

I want that all the write operations across the 10 different steps should be under One transaction which will get committed in the 11th step.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: that isn't how Spring Batch is supposed to be used, so no there isn't. If that is what you want don't use Spring Batch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring batch - One transaction over whole Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031186/spring-batch-one-transaction-over-whole-job)

Comment: `Is there any way to achieve this?` - yes, there is. Implement your own `PlatformTransactionManager` that holds on to a single `Transaction` object until it is time to commit or roll back. However, I am guessing the question is more along the lines of `Is there a readymade way to achieve this without having to write code on my own?`, the answer to which is no, there isn't, as @M.Deinum has correctly pointed out.

Comment: That would also mean tapping into the mechanisms of Spring Batch and find another way of starting/committing a transaction. Next to that it will also interfere with how Spring Batch writes its meta data to the database (assuming a persistent solution is used). Spring Batch isn't designed to work this way, so it isn't the right tool for the job (no pun intended).

Comment: No I don't want any ready mode code as suggested by @manish I just want the concepts or guidance to do this if available

Comment: Can i mark write method in all the steps with @Transactional ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ChainedTransactionManager, check the below URL for your distributed transaction manager to make a chain between them

https://medium.com/swlh/working-with-spring-batch-and-distributed-transaction-772de2219e60