# How to run the spring batch job in one transaction

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data, spring-batch

I have the job which is being scheduled everyday.
The job functionality is below:

1. Reader will read the data from database using JDBCPaging reader.
2. ItemProcessor will process the data by making an API call which returns some updated data.
3. Writer writes the data back into database.

The problem is there is an online processing which reads a particular row, process and update it.

I want to maintain consistency such that I want to update the data which is last processed.
Since the reader, processor and write is done in separate method, how to take the lock and process it.
I am using postgresql database.

Comment: That is not how Spring Batch is working. If you want that, don't use Spring Batch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch - One transaction over whole Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031186/spring-batch-one-transaction-over-whole-job)

Comment: So, there is no proper way. I have to do some workaround. May be  having the lock on process and update. Can I process and update in the processor by synchronizing and writer won't do anything.